# Can we find generating function for $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}\binom{rk-mi-1}{n-1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions

For $n,m,r\in\mathbb{N}$,

let $A_n(m,r)$ be number of $n$-tuples,   $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^n$

such that $1\leq x_1,x_2,...,x_n\leq m$ and $r$ divides  $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n$

I can find that $$ A_n(m,r)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}\binom{rk-mi-1}{n-1}$$

Now I want to find generating function $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n(m,r)x^n$

Thank for your help.

Comment: Do you know of any recurrence relations that $A_n$ satisfies?

Comment: I think recurrence relation seems difficult

Comment: because there are many variables

Comment: when $n=1$, we have
$\sum_{i=0}^1(-1)^i\binom{1}{i}\binom{rk-mi-1}{0}=0$, then $A_1(m,r)=0$.  But when $m \ge r$, shouldn't we have $A_1(m,r) \gt 0$?

Comment: Actually, whatever $n,r,k,m$ don't we have $\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}\binom{rk-mi-1}{n-1}=0$ since it is the $n^{th}$ order backward difference with increment $m$ of $\binom{rk-1}{n-1}$ wich is a polynomial function in the variable $rk-1$ of degree $n-1$?